# How do I remove the List of Figures from the Tables of Contents in Latex?

Tags: latex

I'm using the report class, and I have a table of contents that I would like to start with the introduction. However I'd also like the List of Figures to come after the contents, but not be included in the contents itself.

However at the moment the contents looks like this:

```
Contents
List of Figures vi
1 Introduction 1
```

I'd like to still have the LoF after the contents, but I just want it to not appear in the ToC, is this possible?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 9pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino font
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\chapternumberfont{\Large}
\chaptertitlefont{\huge}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  breaklines=true
}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Authorship Declaration}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{Abstract}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the use of asterisk just after \listoffigures (or \newpage if you are using it) removes the list of figures from the table of contents. Of course the same is valid for the list of tables.

At least it worked for me.